# Why it always say: Undefined index: User

Tags: php, mysql

It always says the same error even I defined the user variable. I used this so that it can print the user name of the user and other details of the user who logged in a restricted page.

#### Code when logging in:

```
  <?php require_once('../Connections/Intranet.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  ....
}

mysql_select_db($database_Intranet, $Intranet);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM useraccounts";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $Intranet) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?><?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['User'];
  $password=$_POST['Password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "Restriction";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "Admin.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_Intranet, $Intranet);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT UserName, Password, Restriction FROM useraccounts WHERE UserName=%s AND Password=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $Intranet) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'Restriction');

    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">
  <label>User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="User" id="User" />
  <p>
    <label>Password :
    <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

#### Code on the user page:

```
  <?php require_once('../Connections/Intranet.php'); ?><?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "ADMIN";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "User.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {    
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($QUERY_STRING) && strlen($QUERY_STRING) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $QUERY_STRING;
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_Intranet, $Intranet);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE UserName = '" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["User"]) . "'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $Intranet) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['UserName']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Restriction:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Restriction']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Division:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Division']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p><?php print_r($_POST) ?>;&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Log out</a></p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: Please reformat the question. Highlight the code and click the {} button.

Comment: Your PHP version must be broken. Because it usually also tells the line number where the error occurs. -- But btw, it's just a debug notice. Working on SQL escaping should have priority.

Comment: could it be the php version the problem? how could i fix it?

Comment: I can't watch this go on anymore. go get yourself a PHP framework

Comment: It Does not read $_post so i use $_SESSION['MM_Username'] and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input name is User not UserName.

This should work:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE UserName = '" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["User"]) . "'";
```

Comment: @pido Please provide more error details, like the line # etc. Is there code missing from the question?

Comment: @pido Did you wrap the word user with quotes? code should be `$_POST["User"]` not `$_POST[User]`

Comment: (Notice: Undefined index: User in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet\Admin.php on line 106)  
the line number 106 is this: $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE UserName = '$_POST[User]'";

Comment: @pido "i still get the same error" implies that you tried the solution i posted. You mixed and matched. Please replace your line 106 with the code i posted. Then let me know if you still get the same error.

Comment: yes i tried your solution.. and i cant make it work.. The same error message i got..

Comment: would you like to see my full code? may some code conflicts to the statement.. usually its just a simple step but now im having trouble in this.. may be its because of the restriction i put?

Comment: @pido Try a `print_r($_POST);` and see what name/values are being posted.

Comment: i got shock it does not show anything.. i use print_r($_POST) and it show nothig >  Array ( ) ;

Comment: i figured it out.. i use the $_SESSION['MM_Username'].. thanks for your help buddy!

Comment: @pido Where are you getting the error? could it be you are redirecting the user to `redirectLoginSuccess`? Try using a http debugging tool like fidler2 to see what requests are going on.

Answer (score 1):

In your login form, you wrote:

```
<input type="text" name="User" id="User" />
```

However at your back end code, you wrote:

```
$_POST['UserName']
```

instead of

```
$_POST['User']
```

Comment: Sorry too many edits i made.. but still i got stock on the same error.. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're still getting the same error, then you didn't define that variable.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$post = array( 'color' => 'blue' );
echo $post['color']; // "blue"
echo $post['food']; // Undefined index: food
```

Try `var_dump($_POST)`. Is the "User" key defined?

Comment: yes the user key is defined in the login page.. i call it in the user page but it seems it does not recognize the variable

Comment: Are you sending a POST request to the user page? Put your `var_dump($_POST)` just before the assignment of `$query_Recordset1`.

Comment: i try print_r($_POST); but it shows nothing.. means it does not read any variable? why?

Comment: i figured it out.. i use the $_SESSION['MM_Username'].. thanks for your help buddy!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case sensitive. MySQL is case sensitive on certain OSes (eg. Linux), but not on others. Perhaps it has something to do with that?

Comment: i check it many times but still does not work.. it always get back to that problem